# Validate form ignoring Required validations

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, validation

I need to submit a form in 2 different ways (possibly with 2 differents buttons).

One of them is a normal button: it validates all the inputs with all of their rules in the normal way.

The second button is a little strange: it must validate all the conditions EXCEPT for "Required" conditions. In other words, it have to ignore the Required conditions but doesn't ignore other conditions.

How can I overwrite the validation method for one of the submits?

EDIT: I use ModelState.IsValid to check if validation is correct or not. Is there any way to overwrite ModelState method to doesn't check [Required] attributes?

**In short words: Is there a way that ModelState.IsValid ignore only [Required] attributes?**

Comment: You mean you need to be able to validate that, say, a phone number is numerice but if required is off you don't care if it's blank?

Comment: Exactly, I need something like that. Something to validate data types and other bussiness logic except [Required].

But, I need other button that validates all. This is why I need to keep the attributes in fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I were building it, I'd put a pair of radio buttons on the form to set a bool that'd determine whether I enfoced non-blank entries in the required fields. Then, on button click, if enforceReqs check that the required fields aren't blank, then follow it with a verification block that validates either data is valid OR blank. Something like:

```
bool enforce = radioEnfoce.Checked
string name = //set name
string phone = //set phone
string address = //set address
string email = //set email

if (enforce)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || //Keep checking all required fields.)
    {
        //some error message
        //return?
    }//if required entry is empty.

    //Repeat for all required fields.

}//if enforcing

if ( (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) && !phoneIsValid())
{
    //Do stuff. Entry isn't valid.
}
//Repeat for all input data.
```

This way you don't have to copy/paste the verification block, since it allows blank entries, and it can because you already checked for blanks (if you care to catch them this run).

Comment: I was using ModelState.IsValid to check if all the conditions are valid. With your approach lamentably I will have to forget ModelState.IsValid and check every condition manually. What it is a large work because I need to do it in many form.

Comment: Ah, yeah, only thing I can think of is to implement this logic by remove modelstate[Required] and manually checking existence. Sorry, probably not much help.